# Converting large CSV file to Parquet using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Im converting a large CSV file as Parquet file (pyspark) while it looks good until number of rows reaches certain range after that I consistently get following error when I read it

```
Expected 1503 values in column chunk /data.parquet offset 4 but got 6206 values instead over 1 pages ending at file offset 66695
```

However, it is not complaining when I write CSV as Parquet file. Is there any specific configuration we should do to handle large CSV file?

Comment: Can you show the code you used?

Comment: Im using df.write.parquet(file_tmp, mode='overwrite') and then FileUtil to copy and merge the files. I found that parquet file is corrupted after certain size.

Comment: I have re-partitioned and write it., that works !!df.repartition(1).write.parquet(file_tmp, mode='overwrite')